# Windows 10 HDMI - Enable 9.2 channel audio

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, home-theater

I have a NUC model NUC7CJYH running Windows 10. The NUC is HDMI 2.0a capable which means it can stream up to 32 channels of audio. The NUC is connected to a Pioneer SC-LX57 9.2 channel receiver which is also HDMI 2.0a capable. The PC is connected with a "Premium HDMI" cable with a QR code proofing it's indeed a HDMI 2.0 cable.

However, I don't see an option to specify more than 7.1 channels for the audio device:

[image: Windows 10 limited to 7.1 audio]

How to enable the 9.2-channel audio mode in Windows 10?

Comment: Dolby Atmos may be used for that, but your hardware must conform.

Comment: @harrymc thank you for looking into this. Will it allow me to stream 9.2 PCM audio or the feature allows streaming only Atmos-encoded content?

Comment: The possible channel formats are transferred from the Pioneer to the NUC via ELD ("EDID-like data") embedded in [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data). So the first step should be to look at that and see if it has 9.2, or not. I know how to access this data on Linux, but not on Windows, but maybe somebody else knows...

Comment: @dirkt Indeed, Windows sees the receiver as an 8-channel device. I sent a message to Pioneer support for details.

Comment: The basic Windows speaker configuration (DirectSound compatible) cannot exceed 7.1 from what I found (`KSAUDIO_CHANNEL_CONFIG` struct). Internally, structures go up to 10.1.7.

Comment: @DanielB thank you for the finding. Do you know anything about limitations of the Linux audio subsystem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specifications](https://www.google.com/search?q=nuc7cjyh%20specs&oq=NUC7CJYH&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.2138j0j4&client=ms-android-att-us&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#lbl=DET) for your NUC model NUC7CJYH,  it only supports up to 7.1 surround sound. Therefore, it is not capable of 9.2 surround sound.

Comment: I bet that only applies to the “regular” sound processor but not HDMI.

Comment: @DanielB HDMI only carries the signal, it can't create 9.2 surround sound. If the built-in sound card doesn't support it, he can't do it.

Comment: That’s correct, but every HDMI-capable graphics card I know includes a dedicated audio processor.

Comment: The specification you're referring says it's a HDMI 2.0a device. HDMI 2.0a supports up to 32 channels of audio. I'm trying to stream audio through HDMI, not a built-in sound card.

Comment: This is no hardware limitation. More than 7.1ch needs HDMI 2.0, but according to the OP his NUC has HDMI 2.0a. According to Microsoft, Windows 10 can do 8.1.4.4 (8 channels on ear leves, 4 above, 4 below and the usual LFE channel: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/coreaudio/spatial-sound

Answer (score 0):

None of the AV receivers with more than 7.1 channels actually support more than 7.1 channels via HDMI as plain PCM audio stream. The limitation is even mentioned in the technical data section of all of their manuals! I frequently checked new models for the last few years.

It seems like the industry is too lazy to implement the HDMI 2.0 spec (more than 8 channels needs new data structures, the old standard cannot be repurposed).

And maybe Dolby and DTS also have some weight in the decisions, such that content creators are forced to buy into their licenses if they want to provide more than 7.1ch content (yes, I'm looking at Battlefront and Battlefield).

I sometimes wonder if someone should write a virtual audio driver that bundles several audio sinks into one. Using 2 HDMI 1.4 ports would be sufficient for 14 channel audio! And two $250 7.1ch AVR are also much cheaper than one 11.2ch AVR!